# Install an app from the appCatalog using javascript CSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, app

I'm trying to install an app in a site from the AppCatalog using the javascript CSOM

I get the apps from the App Catalog using

```
req.apps = SP.AppCatalog.getAppInstances(clientContext, oWebsite);
```

I exec the async call and I get the AppInstances.

but now I'm trying to use the install method (to install the app in the site) but nothings happens (I don't have errors but the app isn't installed)

Comment: Look in the ULS logs, still no errors related to this?

Comment: it doesn't seem to have errors. there are traces about the CSOM execution, but no errors.

Comment: Then add the code there you try to install the app :)

Comment: Hello Benja, I am also working on something similar to this.. Will you share your main code on how to get apps in AppCatalog.. It would be of great help.. Thanks in Advance